# How to pass the parameter of a function by object reference (C++)

Tags: c++, object, boost, reference

I want to pass the parameter of a function by object reference. If I write the code like this:

```
#include <boost\thread\thread.hpp>
class Data 
{
public:
    Data();
    ~Data();
    void func(boost::mutex  &mut);
private:

    boost::condition_variable   condData;
    boost::mutex                mutData;
};


void Data::func(boost::mutex  &mut)
{
    Data* data = this;
    data->mutData = mut;// Here a syntax error
}
```

Here  `data->mutData = mut;` shows a error

`Error: "boost::mutex &boost::mutex:.Operator=(boost::mutex &)" can not be accessed` on equal sign.

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Not immediately relevant but are you using C++11? If so, use `std::thread` etc. But a compilation error such as the one you have is most likely due to a misuse of the object; refer to the boost documentation (which is better than it once was) for the correct way to use `boost::mutex`. And a fair question, plus one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design, a mutex cannot be copied or assigned.

Allowing that would invalidate the idea of using a mutex to protect some resource. If everyone have their own copy of the mutex, there is no longer a single lock for the shared resource.

Comment: It cannot even be moved, we might add.

Answer (score 0):

`boost::mutex` inherits from [`boost::noncopyable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#Class_noncopyable) and can’t be copied or assigned. (The error message you posted says that the assignment operator is private. Thus you are not allowed to use it.) If you want to share a `boost::mutex` object, you have to use a pointer or a global variable.